# How to get subclasses, supperclasses after update OWL API 3.X to 4.X?

Tags: ontology, owl-api

Using version 3.X we used to get classexpressions like this

```
cls.getSuperClasses(ont)
```

Updating version 4.X we try to use EntitySearcher but it return empty sets.

```
EntitySearcher.getSuperClasses(cls, ontology)
```

Full code:

```
public static void test() throws OWLOntologyCreationException {

    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
    OWLOntology ontology;

    File file = new File("assets/ontologies/zebra.owl");
    ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);

    OWLClass cls = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(ontology.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI() + "#" + "Color"));
    Set<OWLClassExpression> parentClasses = collect(EntitySearcher.getSuperClasses(cls, ontology).iterator());

    System.out.println(parentClasses.size());
}

public static Set<OWLClassExpression> collect(Iterator<OWLClassExpression> i) {

    Set<OWLClassExpression> set = new HashSet<OWLClassExpression>();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        OWLClassExpression res = i.next();
        set.add(res);
    }
    return set;
}
```

Used ontology is zebra.owl /Zebra Riddle or Einstein riddle - [DB link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9n4qtbwv9wo0d0/zebra.owl?dl=0)

Expected result (3.X or Protege):

```
inverse (has_color) some House
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

`ontology.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI()`

In OWLAPI 4 getOntologyIRI does not return an `IRI` but an `Optional<IRI>` to represent the fact that an ontology might not have an IRI.

If you change the code to

`ontology.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().get()`

your code works and prints `1`.

I've added this fix to [the migration suggestions](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Migrate-from-version-3.4-and-3.5-to-4.0)

Comment: Shame on me :/ . Thank you.